# How to set up SVN with nginx+php-fpm?

Tags: svn, nginx, php

I have a working installation of Nginx and PHP-FPM, which its default index directory is /usr/share/nginx/html/

Also, I have a working installation of SVN, it seems the default directory of this is /var/www/

I tried to change in nginx.conf the default path to point to /var/www/html but it didn't worked:

```
    #
# The default server
#
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
         ##** I tried to change the line above to /var/www/html/**
        include        fastcgi_params;
```

What exactly need to change in nginx.conf? or maybe I can change the svn default directory to /usr/share/nginx/html ? How can I do any of both things?

Comment: how do you change the default path?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to provide svn commit access over https through nginx, I don't believe that will be possible. What I would recommend is to have nginx reverse proxy a server with apache + mod_dav_svn. If you'd like, you could have apache live on the same machine as nginx.

Comment: The only thing that I just needed to to is make a svn checkout in the specified directory, but adding a blank space and "." after url.

Comment: That isn't "setting up SVN". That is called "doing a SVN checkout".